# ClientHello only passes one cipher suite as available, causing a handshake error

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

We're running a gradle + java + spring boot backend that communicates with an external server through SOAP. It was originally built using Java 8.

Recently the server has updated its list of accepted cipher suites to ECDHE algorithms, which caused connection issues. Upon further inspection using `-Djavax.net.debug=all` (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` did not log much for some reason) we noticed that our ClientHello looks like this:

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.343 CDT|SignatureScheme.java:283|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.343 CDT|SignatureScheme.java:283|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.364 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: x25519
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp256r1
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp384r1
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: secp521r1
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: x448
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe2048
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe3072
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe4096
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe6144
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:404|Ignore inactive or disabled named group: ffdhe8192
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SupportedGroupsExtension.java:411|no available named group
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: supported_groups
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|ECPointFormatsExtension.java:195|Need no ec_point_formats extension
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.365 CDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|ALL|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.366 CDT|SignatureScheme.java:359|Ignore disabled signature scheme: rsa_md5
javax.net.ssl|INFO|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.366 CDT|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.366 CDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.366 CDT|SessionTicketExtension.java:396|Stateless resumption not supported
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|1F|http-nio-8080-exec-10|2020-05-14 10:35:25.366 CDT|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: session_ticket
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "42 29 61 3C 0F 40 99 21 AC 24 0B BE 2C B4 83 25 CC 42 D5 60 D7 A1 72 F8 DF 7D C5 9D 8A EE 3B 07",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=blah blah blah
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
```

it looks like we're only exposing one cipher suite that's not supported by the server. The people who work on the server were thinking it might be an issue with our x509 certificate, but we tried the same interaction in soapUI with our certificate loaded and the communication is smooth, with the right cipher suite chosen. Another team that connects to this server has also run into this issue, but that alone does not indicate that it's a server issue.

From my understanding, a normal ClientHello is supposed to expose the client's available ciphers and the server will pick one from the list. We know we have the ciphers available because we ran this script: 
`jrunscript -e "java.util.Arrays.asList(javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().getSupportedCipherSuites()).stream().forEach(println)"`.

In other posts I've seen that `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` will show if the application  is rejecting certain ciphers, but we have not been able to see that for reasons beyond my understanding. We do not manage the SSL connection directly and largely leave that up to the built in stuff, which I only have a fuzzy understanding of. Someone I work with said  it could be an issue with `HttpURLConnection`, but doesn't know exactly what.

Another team member has posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782535/force-use-of-cipher-when-connecting-to-foreign-service), which goes into some of the things we have tried.

My main question is what could be preventing our application from sending more ciphers? I'm not sure if it has always been this way, but its a possibility since we don't manage the connection ourselves. If we must go down the route of manually setting the ciphers we pass, how would we go about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Messed around with gradle and imported apache HTTPCore as well as updating our HTTPClient to the latest version. The next clean build flagged a warning that a class was deprecated, and in that same file was the configuration for cipher suites to send. For the future, it looked like this :

```
    @Bean
    public SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext) {
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext,
                new String[]{TLS_VERSION_1_2, TLS_VERSION_1_0},
                new String[]{
                        "PUT YOUR CIPHERS HERE",
                        "AND HERE"
                },
                null);
    }
```

with SSLConnectionSocketFactory being deprecated.

So the issue was we weren't aware this existed in our codebase, but if we had done a text search for the single cipher we would've found it in the project earlier. Oof